# How to do integration testing for application that uses POP3 and SMTP?

Tags: testing, smtp, email, pop3

I've been using [smtp4Dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) to test sending emails without them actually reaching anyone.

Now I want to be able to also test retrieving emails from an email server using POP3 but smtp4dev doesn't seem to support this.

Is there an application I can use to test both SMTP for sending mail and POP3 for retrieving mail on my local system?

Alternatively what would be a suitable lightweight application for testing mail retrieval with POP3?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable work around http://csns.calstatela.edu/wiki/content/cysun/course_materials/hmailserver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) can be configured to behave as a dummy smtp, pop3 and/or imap server

These are instructions from http://csns.calstatela.edu/wiki/content/cysun/course_materials/hmailserver

> 1. [Download hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/index.php?page=download)
> 2. During installation, choose:
>
>    - Full installation
>    - Use built-in database engine
>    - Run hMailServer Administrator
> 3. In hMailServer Administrator:
>
>    - Add a domain localhost.localdomain
>    - Add a catch-all address (Domain -> localhost.localdomain -> Advanced -> Catch-all address) , e.g. cysun@localhost.localdomain. If an email is sent to this domain but the address of the email does not match any existing account under this domain, the catch-all address will get this email.
>    - Add an account, e.g. cysun@localhost.localdomain .
>    - Under Settings -> Protocols -> SMTP -> Delivery of e-mail, specify the host name to be localhost .
>    - Under Advanced -> IP Ranges, delete Internet. This step is a safety measure to ensure that your email server will only be used locally.
>        Under Advanced -> Auto-ban, uncheck Enabled so your account won't get automatically disabled if you mistype the password a few times.

I also downloaded and installed [thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/) to make it easier to manage emails on the server.